# What does RTL (right to left) mean?

Tags: localization, right-to-left

This is not a joke. I just want to make sure.

Suppose I am writing in a RTL locale. Should it be

```
                                 !World, Hello
```

Or

```
                                 !dlrow, olleH
```

i.e. Should the RTL be at word-level or sentence-level?

(I am just using English for illustration)

Comment: Why should it be closed?

Comment: I'm not sure your example demonstrates what you're asking. Shouldn't the comparison be between `,olleH !dlrow` and `!dlrow ,olleH`?

Comment: Thx. I got what you mean. I have updated my question.

Comment: This is by no means a simple problem. There are numerous complexities in handling RTL text and the level at which markup should be applied to make it work. Take a look at the W3C discussion on the [BiDi Algorithm](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/) for a flavour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Languages like Arabic customarily start their writing at the top right corner of the page, and produce lines of characters to the left.  Such languages are said to be RTL (right-to-left) languages, unlike English which is written from the top left corner and produces lines to the right (an LTR — left-to-right — language).

The data in memory is still stored with the first character first (lowest address), and subsequent characters following, but the data is displayed differently.

Addressing your question about 'Hello, World!', it is done for the whole content, so sentences, or paragraphs, or chapters at a time.

Not:

```
,olleH !dlrow
```

but:

```
!dlrow ,olleH
```

or even:

```
                                                                          !dlrow ,olleH
```

(I'm not sure if that's going to break at the right place for everyone.  On my screen, it is as far right as possible.)

Comment: Seems we have a mutual understanding.

Comment: Way back many moons ago, I did some work out in Kuwait, and there were Arabic terminals (based on DEC VT-52, IIRC) that could be switched between English and Arabic modes.  Arabic letters are also interesting because the same letter has different graphical forms when at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end of a word.  See Unicode [Arabic](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf) chart for the basic forms, but note that the display (discussed in [Chapter 8](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch08.pdf)) varies depending on the position of the letter in the word.